# Avoid __init__ and super boilerplate when inheriting

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # some constructor based on the kwargs
        pass

class Child(Base):

    # the method I would like to avoid
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Is there a way to avoid the boilerplate of calling `__init__` and `super` in the Child class? In this package, users would inherit from the base class very often, but I would like to avoid them using `__init__` with `super` each time, especially since the pattern would never change. it still needs to take in keyword arguments however.

I imagine this is possible using `__new__` or a metaclass, but there has to be a simpler method using something like `@classmethod` in the base class?

EDIT: Using python3

Comment: are you on python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: Omit the `__init__` method on the child class unless you need to extend the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need specific initialization in the child class, you can omit the `__init__`:

```
class Base:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # some constructor based on the kwargs
        pass

class Child(Base):
    pass
```

Otherwise, you should use it this way:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # some constructor based on the kwargs
        pass

class Child(Base):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #...additional specific initialization
```

Comment: Wow don't know why I didn't think about that. Works perfectly.